# Centering sub/superscript of operator after scaling

Tags: math-operators, subscripts, superscripts, scale

I would like to make the sub-/supperscript smaller 10% and use package scalerel to do that.
Everything is fine until I find out that the sub-/superscript in operators are also scaled but they are not center aligned.

Any idea for fixing this issue. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subdepth}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\mathcode`_="8000 
\catcode`_=12 
\mathcode`^="8000 
\catcode`^=12
\begingroup
\catcode`_=\active
\catcode`^=\active
\gdef_#1{\ensuremath{\sb{\begingroup \hstretch{.9}{\vstretch{.9}{#1}} \endgroup}}}
\gdef^#1{\ensuremath{\sp{\begingroup \hstretch{.9}{\vstretch{.9}{#1}} \endgroup}}}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\(a^2 \qquad \sum\limits_{2}^{3}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Peripherally related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436142/vertical-positioning-of-superscripts-and-subscripts-in-math-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my other answer, I suggested an alternate approach to the OP's dilemma, through the use of the `\DeclareMathSizes` macro.  However, in a comment, the OP asked if I could also resolve the issue using his original approach.

When I first looked at the OP's result, I though the mis-centering of the scripts was related to my `scalerel` package.  However, upon closer inspection, I found that if I replaced the OP's `\hstretch{.9}{\vstretch{.9}{#1}}` with a `\scalebox{.9}{#1}`, the problem persisted.

I found, through experimentation, that if I wrapped the super/sub-script redefinitions in an `\hbox`, proper centering was restored.

Using the facilities of the `scalerel` package to import the current math style into the `\hbox`, I recast the OP's redefinitions in a way that preserved horizontal centering.  In this MWE, I also set the rescale to 0.7, rather than 0.9, merely to emphasize the resizing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subdepth}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\mathcode`_="8000 
\catcode`_=12 
\mathcode`^="8000 
\catcode`^=12
\begingroup
\catcode`_=\active
\catcode`^=\active
\gdef_#1{\sb{\ThisStyle{\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}}
\gdef^#1{\sp{\ThisStyle{\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\(a^2 \qquad \sum\limits_{2}^{3}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

As to why the `\hbox` is required, I suspected that the super/sub-scripts performed an `\unhbox` as part of their process, and therefore needed an `\hbox` on which to act.

The following MWE, in which I had `\unhbox` announce its arrival, confirmed my suspicions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subdepth}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\mathcode`_="8000 
\catcode`_=12 
\mathcode`^="8000 
\catcode`^=12
\begingroup
\catcode`_=\active
\catcode`^=\active
\gdef_#1{\sb{\ThisStyle{\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}}
\gdef^#1{\sp{\ThisStyle{\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{$\SavedStyle#1$}}}}}
\endgroup

\let\svunhbox\unhbox
\def\unhbox{*\svunhbox}
\begin{document}
\(a^2 \qquad \sum\limits_{2}^{3}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I would instead recommend the use of `\DeclareMathSizes` to address the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{subdepth}
%\usepackage{scalerel}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{6}{5}

\begin{document}
xxx\(a^2 \qquad \sum\limits_{2}^{3}\)zzz
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the reference scale, in which the scripts are slightly larger:

[image]

Comment: thank you. I will try this. But for my old code, is there any way to utilize it?

Comment: @NuecTah It is an interesting issue.  At first, I thought my `scalerel` package to be responsible.  However, if I replace the h- and v-stretches with a simple `\scalebox`, the same shifted behavior occurs.  I have not yet resolved why, but I will keep on looking.